# Perform incremental learning of XGBClassifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

After referring to [this link](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/python-package/xgboost/training.py) I was able to successfully implement incremental learning using `XGBoost`. I want to build a classifier and need to check the predict probabilities i.e. `predict_proba()` method. This is not possible if I use `XGBoost`. While implementing `XGBClassifier.fit()` instead of `XGBoost.train()` I am not able to perform incremental learning. The `xgb_model` parameter of the `XGBClassifier.fit()` takes the `XGBoost` while I want to provide an `XGBClassifier`.

Is it possible to perform incremental learning of `XGBClassifier` since I need to make use of `predict_proba()` method?

Working Code:

```
import XGBoost as xgb

train_data = xgb.DMatrix(X, y)
model = xgb.train(
    params = best_params, 
    dtrain = train_data, 
)

new_train_data = xgb.DMatrix(X_new, y_new)
retrained_model = xgb.train(
    params     = best_params, 
    dtrain     = new_train_data, 
    xgb_model  = model
)
```

Above code runs perfectly but does not has an option of `retrained_model.predict_proba()`

Non-working Code:

```
import XGBoost as xgb

xgb_model = xgb.XGBClassifier(**best_params)
xgb_model.fit(X, y)

retrained_model = xgb.XGBClassifier(**best_params)
retrained_model.fit(X_new, y_new, xgb_model = xgb_model)
```

Above code does not work since it expects an `XGBoost` model or `Booster instance XGBoost` model to be loaded.

**Error Trace:**

```
[11:27:51] WARNING: ../src/learner.cc:1061: Starting in XGBoost 1.3.0, the default evaluation metric used with the objective 'binary:logistic' was changed from 'error' to 'logloss'. Explicitly set eval_metric if you'd like to restore the old behavior.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/project/Data_Training.py", line 530, in train
    retrained_model.fit(X_new, y_new, xgb_model = xgb_model)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xgboost/core.py", line 422, in inner_f
    return f(**kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xgboost/sklearn.py", line 915, in fit
    callbacks=callbacks)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xgboost/training.py", line 236, in train
    early_stopping_rounds=early_stopping_rounds)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xgboost/training.py", line 60, in _train_internal
    model_file=xgb_model)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xgboost/core.py", line 1044, in __init__
    raise TypeError('Unknown type:', model_file)
TypeError: ('Unknown type:', XGBClassifier(base_score=0.5, booster='gbtree', colsample_bylevel=1,
              colsample_bynode=1, colsample_bytree=1, gamma=0, gpu_id=-1,
              importance_type='gain', interaction_constraints='',
              learning_rate=1, max_delta_step=0, max_depth=3,
              min_child_weight=1, missing=nan, monotone_constraints='()',
              n_estimators=100, n_jobs=32, num_parallel_tree=1, random_state=0,
              reg_alpha=0, reg_lambda=1, scale_pos_weight=1, subsample=0.7,
              tree_method='exact', validate_parameters=1, verbosity=None))
```

Comment: What does `'Unknown type:', model_file` in the error message imply? Is `xgb_model` already in the working space, or you load it from a file in code not shown here? If it is so, please post all the *relevant* code here - see how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @desertnaut `xgb_model` is the initial trained model using `XGBClassifier`. And then `xgb_model` is also a parameter for `XGBClassifier`. Apologies. I should have used a different name for initial trained model. To my understanding, the error is the line that I just mentioned above the `error trace`. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs:

> **xgb_model** – file name of stored XGBoost model or ‘Booster’ instance[.] XGBoost model to be loaded before training (allows training continuation).

So you should be able to use `xgb_model.get_booster()` to retrieve the underlying `Booster` instance and pass that.

---

Also, you *can* get predicted probabilities out of the native xgboost API; `Booster.predict` returns probabilities when `objective='binary:logistic'`.

Comment: Awesome.!! I replaced the respective lines with `>>> retrained_model = xgb.XGBClassifier(objective='binary:logistic', **best_params)
>>> retrained_model.fit(X_new, y_new, xgb_model = xgb_model.get_booster())` and it worked flawlessly.

Comment: The probabilities received using `.predict()` are single values. Was wondering which class probability does it correspond.

Comment: I believe xgboost requires labels to be 0,1 for `objective='binary:logistic'`, and that then the predictions are probability of 1.

Comment: Yes you are right, I cross checked the `XGBClassifier` and `booster` results, they match for `target=1`. And yes, the target labels for me are 0 and 1.